# Zend Framework - using alias within a nested query results in issues

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm using ZF 1.12 and I'm trying to create the following query:

```
SELECT table1.*, (select count(t2.id) from table2 as t2) AS count_t2 FROM table1
```

and here's my attempt:

```
$query = $this->getDbTable()->select()
        ->from(array('table1'), array(
            '*',
            'count_t2' => '(select count(t2.id) from table2 AS t2)'
        ));
```

However, the resulted query is wrong, I believe due to using alias t2:

```
SELECT `table1`.*, (select count(t2.id) from table2 AS `t2)` FROM `table1`
```

Is there a sollution for using alias within a nested query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer after a few minutes.

For some strange reason, using allias within a nested query is possible without the `AS` keyword.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer please? That would help future visitors. Also, the `as` keyword for alias is option in MySQL.

Comment: I will post it as an answer as soon as I am able to mark it so, i.e. two days time